# Problema con TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio al intentar instalar complementos

Tags: jasper-reports

instalé TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio 6.9.0 y al ingresar al menú "*Help > Install New Software*" y seleccionar "*--All Available Sites--*" en el desplegable "*Work with*" recibo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La excepción de tipo "*org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException*" es:

```
Unable to connect to repository http://jasperstudio.sf.net/jssproductrepo_E4_CE/content.xml
Connection timed out: connect
```

¿Alguién más ha tenido este problema?, ¿qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?, estoy utilizando la última versión del editor y del servidor (JasperReports Server 7.2.0), ambos en su versión de "Comunidad".

Answer (score 0):

Edité el listado de orígenes de actualización:

```
Windows > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites
```

Añadí uno nuevo llamado "SourceForge" y le asigné la URL "https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperstudio/files/updatesite/6.9.0/":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]